# Apache NIFI Flowfile from PUTSQL processor is not sending to Failed or Retry queue

Tags: apache-nifi

I have large data and using PUTSQL processor inserting into the database.
While inserting the data, I have observed some failures saying `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

Here is the error log:

[image: exception error got in logs]

Connected FAILED and RETRY queues from PUTSQL to PUTFILE to capture the query when its failed. But when PUTSQL failed, flowfile is not sending to the queue by PUTSQL.
Please let us know how can I see the failed query in this scenario??

One more question:

When I did Data Provenance on the PUTSQL processor, it's not showing the current data and seems to be showing only 1000 entried.
Is there any way to see the full data for a particular processor??

Comment: ,Before PutSQL which processor you have?

Comment: The Provenance user interface has a limit of 1000 records for display.  If you change the search filter, you can narrow down on the recent records you need.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already [answered quite elaborately on HCC](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/94590/apache-flow-file-from-putsql-processor-is-not-send.html) . Here is the key section that explains the situation:

The flowfile isn't going out the FAILED connection because the session is rolled back to the incoming queue. ... Meaning the flowfile is penalized and then put back on the incoming queue for the PutSQL processor.